# Fatal error: Class 'eftec\bladeone\BladeOne' not found

Tags: php

I am using PHP 5.5.9 and have installed the [library BladeOne](https://github.com/EFTEC/BladeOne) in my composer file:

```
{
    "name": "test",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "test",
            "email": "test@test.com"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "eftec/bladeone": "^3.0",
        "davechild/textstatistics": "1.*",
        "hassankhan/config": "^1.0"
    }
}
```

I am running my script the following way:

```
<?php
require "vendor/autoload.php";
Use eftec\bladeone;
use DaveChild\TextStatistics as TS;

$views = __DIR__ . '/views';
$cache = __DIR__ . '/cache';

define("BLADEONE_MODE",1); // (optional) 1=forced (test),2=run fast (production), 0=automatic, default value.
$blade=new bladeone\BladeOne($views,$cache); <----- Here I get the error!
```

However, I get the following error here:

```
Fatal error: Class 'eftec\bladeone\BladeOne' not found in /home/ubuntu/workspace/testExample.php on line 10
```

Any suggestions why the library cannot be used in my script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [per the docs](https://github.com/EFTEC/BladeOne#usage) you are supposed to add the namespace to the autoloading of composer by adding it to your composer.json.

```
"autoload": {
  "psr-4": {
    "eftec\\": "vendor/eftec/"
  }
}
```

then, (again, the docs say) run `composer update`. I suppose though that `composer dump-autoload` would suffice.