# It will be displayed as Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'eftec\bladeone' not found

Tags: php

I was trying to test [BladeOne](https://github.com/EFTEC/BladeOne) using PHP7.3.

composer.json

```
{
  "name": "TEST",
    "require": {
      "eftec/bladeone": "^3.33"
    },
  "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
      "eftec\\": "vendor/eftec/"
      }
    }
}
```

test.php

```
require "vendor/autoload.php";

Use eftec\bladeone;

$views = __DIR__ . '/views';
$cache = __DIR__ . '/cache';
$blade = new BladeOne($views,$cache,BladeOne::MODE_AUTO);
// $blade -> setAuth( ' johndoe ' , ' admin ' );
echo $blade->run("hello",array("variable1"=>"value1"));
```

This error appears when you run it.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'eftec\bladeone' not found in /*/test.php on line 8
Error: Class 'eftec\bladeone' not found in /*/test.php on line 8
```

I also found a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51506804/fatal-error-class-eftec-bladeone-bladeone-not-found) like this but it didn't work.

Why does this error occur?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `Use eftec\bladeone;` to `use eftec\bladeone\BladeOne;`.

And remove:

```
"autoload": {
"psr-4": {
  "eftec\\": "vendor/eftec/"
  }
}
```

From your composer.json.

Hope help you.

Answer (score 0):

You included only the namespace, not the class name

Change your `Use` statement by this one :

```
use eftec\bladeone\BladeOne;
```

**Or** instantiate the class like this :

```
$blade = new bladeone\BladeOne($views,$cache,BladeOne::MODE_AUTO);
```

(Don't do both)

Comment: I was able to solve it by the above method!
However, the following method did not solve the problem and resulted in the same error.

Comment: Did you cleared the cache of the application, if you're suing some frameworks ?

Comment: Do you mean ./cache?
I tried to delete it, but it didn't work.